# Check jquery array of objects for matching key. += value if match, push new object if not

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

User will fill in a table of data, then I need to iterate the table, group the byt he id and make sure each group == 100.

My plan is to loop through the table rows, make the key:value object, check the array for matching key.  If the key matches, then add the value to the existing array object.  If no match, push the new item.

Assuming this array:

```
var gidArr =
[
    {   
        gid: '123',
        ratio: '20'
    },
    {   
        gid: '123',
        ratio: '40'
    },
    {   
        gid: '432',
        ratio: '50'
    },

]
```

the result should be:

```
{ gid:123, ratio:60 },
{ gid:432, ration: 50}
```

Couple things I have tried:

```
function GIDRatio(gid, ratio) {
    this.gid = gid;
    this.ratio = parseFloat(ratio);
}
        var item = new GIDRatio(gid, ratio);

1:
        if(gid in gidArr) {
            gidArr.ratio += item.ratio;
        } else {
            gidArr.push(item);
        }

2:

    $.each(gidArr, function(i, v) {
        if(v.gid === item.gid) {
             v.ratio += item.ratio;
        } else {
             gisArr.push(item);
        }
    })
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8vw4eehs/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `Array.reduce` method to convert your original array into a new structure.

Inside your `reduce` function, just check if `acc` i.e., your `accumulated array` has `gid` already available. If not then push in the array. If yes, then calculate the total of `ratio` and update the `ratio`.

```js
var gidArr =
[
    {   
        gid: '123',
        ratio: '20'
    },
    {   
        gid: '123',
        ratio: '40'
    },
    {   
        gid: '432',
        ratio: '50'
    },

];

const newArr = gidArr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if(acc.some(x => x.gid === cur.gid)) {
    acc.map(x => {
      if(x.gid === cur.gid) {
        x.ratio = (+x.ratio) + (+cur.ratio);
      }
      return x;
    });
  } else {
    acc.push(cur);
  }
  return acc;
},[])

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Thanks much, been banging my head on this for a little while.  I don't recognize and of the methods people are answering with, so looks like I need to buy a new jquery book and do some more reading.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to covert into a `hashtable` and then accumulate the `ratio` - see demo below:

```js
var gidArr=[{gid:'123',ratio:'20'},{gid:'123',ratio:'40'},{gid:'432',ratio:'50'}];

var hash = gidArr.reduce(function(p,c){
  if(p[c.gid])
    p[c.gid].ratio += +c.ratio;
  p[c.gid] = p[c.gid] || c;
  p[c.gid].ratio = +p[c.gid].ratio;
  return p;
},Object.create(null))

var result = Object.keys(hash).map(function(e){
    return hash[e];
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var gidArr = [
  {gid: '123', ratio: '20'}, 
  {gid: '123', ratio: '40'}, 
  {gid: '432', ratio: '50'},
  {gid: '123', ratio: '40'}
];

/* Creating an array of objects */ 

var obj = gidArr.reduce((a,b) => (a[b.gid] = b.gid in a ? a[b.gid]+(+b.ratio):(+b.ratio), a),{});
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(x => ({[x]:obj[x]}));

console.log(arr, "\n---------------------------")

/* Filtering based on values being 100 */

var result = arr.filter( o => Object.values(o)[0] === 100 );
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```